SCPI commands to instrument work from PC, not from microcontroller through UART-to-USB bridge
TLDR: Sending commands to a piece of lab equipment through USB works from a PC, but not from a microcontroller. Is this a driver issue? What else could cause this problem?

I've been working on a project that controls an instrument wirelessly through SCPI-like ASCII commands send to an instrument through a USB port. For reference, the instrument is an Associated Research Hipot Tester that accepts the commands TEST\n and RESET\n to mimic the controls found on the instruments front panel. Also, the connection is established with a 38,400 baud rate, with a 8 data bits, 1 stop bit, no parity format.
I can send the commands directly from my PC and everything works fine. However, sending the same commands from a microcontroller does not work. A software serial port on the microcontroller is connected to a CP2102 serial to USB converter, and the baud rate setting is the same. The only difference I have noticed when looking at the output of the microcontroller is that TEST\n is converted to TEST\r\n for some reason through the CP2102 chip or the microcontroller. The instrument is tolerant of an extra \r as a command terminator, as a trial of the command sent directly from the PC to the instrument as TEST\r\n works.
My question is: Why does the PC work to send commands to this instrument through USB, but the microcontroller cannot when the commands going to the instrument look identical? I suspect the issue may be that the PC uses a driver to interface with the instrument. If this is the case, what is the driver doing? Can I sniff the connection somehow to mimic the driver behavior from the microcontroller? Additionally, the user manual links to a driver needed to control the equipment, but I have never had to install it for the PC to recognize the lab equipment as a COM port.

Isn't the serial-to-USB converter for converting USB to Serial (i.e. a USB Slave ?), not a USB Master -- so it can't send commands to another USB Slave.

This may be the problem. Thanks!

@TualatinLab Which lab equipment (make/model) it is and to which port you have connected the CP2103 USB side? To a host or device port? Does your equipment support weird USB serial adapters on the host port or something else like USB memory sticks only?

@Justme It's an associated research Hypot Series 3805. The usb side of the adapter chip is connected to the USB port on the hipot tester, and the UART side is connected to an ESP32 microcontroller. The usb port I'm connected to is not the one for memory sticks, and it does allow controlling the instrument when connected directly to a PC. I think the issue is that I was unaware that a USB host may be needed to communicate with the hipot tester.

The unit has USB device port for connecting it to a host PC. This port cannot be connected to CP2102 for RS-232 connectivity. It should also be impossible to connect the CP2102 to this port as there should exist no cable or adapter that would allow you to do it, as connecting two devices without host is useless.
The unit has USB host ports for connecting USB device peripherals like USB memory stick or USB barcode reader.
It will be useless to plug the CP2102 on the front panel - even if it did run some OS like Linux that understands CP2102, you would not have any application expecting anyone to plug in USB serial ports and starting to use it for SCPI commands, unless the manual says it can be used for that.

In addition to Justme's answer:
Some microcontrollers have USB host capabilities, specifically those with built-in USB modules.
Therefore you could investigate what USB device type the Hypot tester uses when connected to a PC. Next, you need to find out how it communicates. Chances are that it implements CDC/ACM functions, which means it is a serial device.
Then you could program your microcontroller to accept that device and communicate with the Hypot tester.
